# Removing screen from Stack after navigating to another screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a TabNavigator with two Tabs `A Tab`  and `B Tab`.
In `B`, there is a StackNavigator `C Stack`. From within this stack, I navigate via `navigation.navigate('A Tab')` to Tab `A`. How can I reset `B Tab`, that when the user navigates back to `B Tab`, there is not the Stack, but the TabNavigator?

I tried

```
  navigation.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [{name: 'B Tab'}],
  });
```

This removes the tack, but this navigates to the sreen `B Tab` which I do not want. I want to stay on current screen.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { name: 'B Tab' }
    ],
  })
);
```